# How to test my download files web API in c#

Tags: c#, web-services, advanced-rest-client

I want to download files from web service . i 've tried to do this but i can't tested it in advanced rest client . here is my code

```
public static HttpResponseMessage FileAsAttachment(string path, string filename)
        {
            if (File.Exists(path))
            {

                HttpResponseMessage result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
                var stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open);
                result.Content = new StreamContent(stream);
                result.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");
                result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment");
                result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName = filename;
                return result;
            }
            return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
        }
```

I always have response " "$id": "1"
"Message": "No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://localhost:36690/api/Data/FileAsAttachment?path=F:\&filename=claims.jpg'."
"MessageDetail": "No action was found on the controller 'Data' that matches the name 'FileAsAttachment'." My controller name is data

Comment: can you post the name of the `Controller` class?

Answer (score 1):

`Action method` should not be static. When I remove `static` from your code it is working.

Why there is a need for declaring it as static method?

Please have a look on the below links.

[Link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6126957/asp-net-mvc-controllers-static-methods)
[Link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33496609/can-mvc-action-method-be-static-or-extension-method)

**Update:** After Comment, try decorating method with `[HttpGet]`

```
 [HttpGet]
 public HttpResponseMessage FileAsAttachment(string path, string filename)
```

Comment: i 'v removed "static" from my code but it still not working i get "Response does not contain any data."

Comment: I still get "Response does not contain any data."

Comment: @prime, Can you update your latest code with the controller here along with the request url you're using to check it ?

Comment: here is my request url : 'http://localhost:36690/api/Data/FileAsAttachment?path=F:\&filename=claims.jpg'.

Comment: @prime, Do you have the controller name as `Data`?

Comment: @prime, Can you update your latest code in the question with controller?