# Why I am getting 400 and 404 error for my WebAPI?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-3.1

I am developing one application using Angular 8 and ASP.Net Core3.1.

[image]

When I am calling all API few are working fine, few are giving 400 error and few of them 404 error.

API giving 400 error :

**MODEL DETAILS**

```
public class ServiceOffer
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string ServiceName { get; set; }
   public string ServiceDescription { get; set; }
   public int ServicePrice { get; set; }
   public bool Status { get; set; }
}
```

**API DETAILS**

```
[Produces("application/json")]
[ApiController]
public class ServiceofferController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("api/v1/serviceoffer/allservice")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
    {
        var objService = new ServiceBL();
        var mob = await objService.GetAllServices();
        return Ok(mob);
    }

    [Route("api/v1/serviceoffer/addservices")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> AddServices([FromBody] ServiceOffer objSer)
    {
        var objService = new ServiceBL();
        int flag = await objService.AddServiceOffer(objSer);
        return Ok(flag);
    }       

    [HttpPut]
    [Route("api/v1/serviceoffer/update")]
    public static async Task<int> UpdateUser([FromBody] ServiceOffer objSer)
    {
        var objService = new ServiceBL();
        return await objService.UpdateServiceOffer(objSer);
    }
}
```

API Working fine : api/v1/serviceoffer/allservice

API giving 400 error: api/v1/serviceoffer/addservices

API Giving 404 error: api/v1/serviceoffer/update

ANGULAR SERVICE

```
getAllServices(url: string): Observable<IServiceOffer[]> {
return this.http
  .get<IServiceOffer[]>(url)
  .pipe(catchError(this.handleError));
}
getServiceById(url: string, id: number): Observable<IServiceOffer> {
const editUrl = `${url}/${id}`;
// console.log(editUrl);
return this.http
  .get<IServiceOffer>(editUrl)
  .pipe(catchError(this.handleError));
}
 // insert new contact details
 saveService(url: string, cust: IServiceOffer): Observable<any> {
  var Customer = JSON.stringify(cust);
  console.log(url);
  return this.http
  .post(url, Customer, httpOptions)
  .pipe(catchError(this.handleError));
 }
// update contact details
 updateService(url: string, customer: IServiceOffer): Observable<any> {
 //const newurl = `${url}/${id}`;
  return this.http
    .put(url, customer, httpOptions)
    .pipe(catchError(this.handleError));
 }
```

CONFIG DETAILS

```
 public class Startup
{
    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }
    public static string ConnectionString { get; private set; }
    public static Dictionary<string, string> MailSettings { get; private set; }
    public Dictionary<string, string> SmsSettings { get; set; }

    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        ConnectionString = Configuration.GetSection("ConnectionString").GetSection("SalesContext").Value;

        //MailSettings = Configuration.GetSection("SMTP").GetChildren()
        //              .Select(item => new KeyValuePair<string, string>(item.Key, item.Value))
        //              .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value);

        MailSettings = Configuration.GetSection("SMTP").GetChildren().ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value);

        services.AddControllersWithViews();
        services.AddSpaStaticFiles(configuration =>
        {
            configuration.RootPath = "ClientApp/dist";
        });

        //services.AddMvc()
        //     .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2)
        //     .ConfigureApiBehaviorOptions(options =>
        //       {
        //         options.SuppressConsumesConstraintForFormFileParameters = true;
        //         options.SuppressInferBindingSourcesForParameters = true;
        //         options.SuppressModelStateInvalidFilter = true;
        //         options.SuppressMapClientErrors = true;
        //         options.ClientErrorMapping[404].Link = "https://httpstatuses.com/404";
        //     });

    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        if (!env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseSpaStaticFiles();
        }

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });

        app.UseSpa(spa =>
        {              

            spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";

            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                spa.UseAngularCliServer(npmScript: "start");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Any one can explain me why I am getting this horrible error?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Show us how you make a requests

Comment: @RomanMarusyk Thanks for your quick response. I have checked, I am getting the right API path during runtime.

Comment: What data do you post? Did you try to debug it? What content of response?

Comment: I am passing the following data for test: {id: 1, serviceName: "Test", serviceDescription: "Test", servicePrice: "1000", status: true} for update. Cannot PUT /api/v1/serviceoffer/update  this is the error browser is showing.

Answer (score 1):

For the 400 Bad Request, make sure set `'Content-Type': 'application/json'` headers and  correct `Customer` Json data. I have tried your test data and it works(Add `[HttpPost]` on action is better).

```
const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' })
};

const cust = { id: 1, serviceName: "Test", serviceDescription: "Test", servicePrice: "1000", status: true } 

var Customer = JSON.stringify(cust);

this.http
  .post("/api/v1/serviceoffer/addservices", Customer, httpOptions)
  .subscribe(result => {
    alert(result);
  }, error => console.error(error));
```

For the `404` Not Found, you need to remove the `static` on the `PUT` action.

Refer to [Can MVC action method be static or extension method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33496609/can-mvc-action-method-be-static-or-extension-method)

**Update 1/14/2020**

Try to use `servicePrice: 1000` instead of `servicePrice: "1000"`.

If you don't want to do above changes.For asp.net core 3.1, it uses `System.Text.Json` for serialization and deserialization.

For using old behavior, you could use Json.NET in an ASP.NET Core 3.1 project by referencing J[son.NET support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio#jsonnet-support).

1) Install-Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson -Version 3.1.0

2) Add `services.AddControllersWithViews().AddNewtonsoftJson();` in startup.cs

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have noticed that the below mention error making this trouble:  "errors":{"$.servicePrice":["The JSON value could not be converted to System.Int32. Path: $.servicePrice | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 78."]}.  In Angular I have declared ServicePrice as number and in Backend Service it is Int32. Please help to resolve this issue.

Comment: @S. S. Maiti I did not note that you were using asp.net core 3.1.I update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

This issue was with .Net Core 3.0. The inbuild  JSON formatter not able to convert from Angular numeric to System.Int32. After going through lot of article I came to know that it is a bug. The solution is to  Install **Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson** package. And add this line Startup.cs 
**services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson();**

It has resolved my issue, now all of my service working fine. Thank to all of you.

Comment: Could you mark my answer to close this thread if you have resolved the problem?